# Architecture test using NetArchTest gives false result when trying to assert sealed class fitness rule

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit, netarchtest

I'm writing Architecture Fitness Test using [NetArchTest](https://github.com/BenMorris/NetArchTest) and I'm trying to `Assert` if all of my Request `Class` are `sealed` using the below test,

```cs
[Fact]
public void Should_Have_Request_To_Be_Sealed()
{
    var result =
        Types.InAssembly(typeof(ApplicationServiceRegistration).Assembly)
            .That()
            .AreClasses()
            .And()
            .Inherit(typeof(IRequest))
            .Should()
            .BeSealed()
            .GetResult();

    Assert.True(result.IsSuccessful);
}
```

Here are the examples of my Request `Class`,

```cs
public class CreateCategoryCommand : IRequest<Result<CategoryDto, BaseError>>
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Code { get; set; }
}

public class CreateClientCommand : IRequest<Result<ClientDto, BaseError>>
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

As we can see, the Request `Class` are not `sealed`, but still the test gets passed.

Am I missing anything? Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out. I should use `ImplementInterface` instead of `Inherit` as shown below,

```cs
[Fact]
public void Should_Have_Request_To_Be_Sealed()
{
    var result =
        Types.InAssembly(typeof(ApplicationServiceRegistration).Assembly)
            .That()
            .AreClasses()
            .And()
            .ImplementInterface(typeof(IRequest)) <-- Changed here
            .Should()
            .BeSealed()
            .GetResult();

    Assert.True(result.IsSuccessful);
}
```